# Part of UIButton area not firing func touchesBegan

Tags: swift, xcode

The Area shown below of a `UIButton` is not registering `touchsBegun` but registering when `touchesEnded` ( which is calling also `touchsBegun`). In addition, the highlight state is not working in this area (again it works only on release but less evident). I have checked also the debug hierarchy but do not see anything strange (I am new to x-code and swift :)). The other part is working as expected. The button to the right works as expected
[image]

hierarchy view 1

[image]

hierarchy view 2 with tree view

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image your storyboard hierarchy view?

Comment: Check that a part of your button does not fall outside of its parent view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the navigation bar. Hiding it has solved the issue. It appears that the navigation bar takes a few pixels from the left of the screen to enable back navigation with a swipe; this was covering the button.

Comment: Is it possible to change the hierarchy of it? and if yes would this by "best practice"?